# How to use a global deferred js file and a separate independant javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Okay so I've deferred one js file (called combination.js) which includes all 'global' / general js that my website needs - using this method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "../js/combination.js"; 
document.body.appendChild(element);
}

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

That sorts the general js out however I need (on certain pages) some javascript for a contact form which **has to be independent** (IE: it cannot be part of the global combination.js file) because I will be changing the code below for certain pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.contactform').submit(function() {
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    var form = this;
    $('.submit', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').after(
          '<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />');
    $('.message', this).slideUp(750, function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $.post(action, {
            name: $('.name', form).val(),
            email: $('.email', form).val(),
            phone: $('.phone', form).val(),
            country: $('.country', form).val(),
            guests: $('.guests', form).val(),
            dayin: $('.dayin', form).val(),
            dayout: $('.dayout', form).val(),
            comments: $('.comments', form).val(),
            verify: $('.verify', form).val()
        },
        function(data) {
            $('.message', form).html(data);
            $('.message', form).slideDown('slow');
            $('img.loader', form).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
            $('.submit', form).removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

but the problem I have is that when I past this code below the deferred javascript ... like so:

**PROBLEM METHOD:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "../js/combination.js"; 
document.body.appendChild(element);
}

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.contactform').submit(function() {
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    var form = this;
    $('.submit', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').after(
          '<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />');
    $('.message', this).slideUp(750, function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $.post(action, {
            name: $('.name', form).val(),
            email: $('.email', form).val(),
            phone: $('.phone', form).val(),
            country: $('.country', form).val(),
            guests: $('.guests', form).val(),
            dayin: $('.dayin', form).val(),
            dayout: $('.dayout', form).val(),
            comments: $('.comments', form).val(),
            verify: $('.verify', form).val()
        },
        function(data) {
            $('.message', form).html(data);
            $('.message', form).slideDown('slow');
            $('img.loader', form).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
            $('.submit', form).removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

The latter javascript (for my form) doesn't execute as it should (vague I know but I'll explain below) WHEREAS when I put that javascript at the bottom of my **combination.js** file, it executes perfectly. As a person with very little knowledge on javascript, I cannot understand why?

The javascript code above is part of the validation process for my contact form(s) and it also (using ajax) displays either a success or error message depending if the form has been sent successfully or not and these messages load on the same page just below the submit button.

But When I put the javascript like in the PROBLEM METHOD above, the success / error messages that this javascript executes opens up in a new blank white page almost like the ajax isn't working.

How can I get the PROBLEM METHOD way to work because I need to include independant js that can't be part of a global js file?

Comment: The second script is activated on document ready - which has already been resolved when its called. However, since the combination.js is still loading (it wasnt included in the evaluation of document.load or document.ready because you injected it after the fact) that code has not actually been parsed. Basically you need to wait to invoke page level customization code until after the load event or your injected script tag. Additionally if jQuery is in the combination.js thats even more problematic because it will be undefined when you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with a basic event emitter:

```
var EventEmitter = {
  events : {},

  on : function(event, func){
     if(!this.events[event]){
        this.events[event] = [];
     }

     this.events[event].push(func);
  },

  emit : function(event){
    var events = this.events[event];
        //check for the event
    if(events){
        //fire them off
        for(var i = 0, l = events.length; i < l; i++){
            events[i]();
        }
    }
  }
};
```

This really simple object lets you store functions until a specific action is emitted by the event emitter.

A basic usage example:

```
var foo = function(){}; //create a function (can be anonymous or not)
EventEmitter.on('bar', foo); //connect the function the 'bar' event
//... somewhere down the script
EventEmitter.emit('bar'); //calls foo
```

Put it in your script before `downloadJSAtOnload` and use it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //event emitter here
    // ...

    function downloadJSAtOnload() {
        var element = document.createElement("script");
        element.onload = function(){
            //call all of your functions waiting for script load
            EventEmitter.emit('load');
        };            
        element.src = "../js/combination.js"; 
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }

    if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
    else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

Then instead of using document ready, use the event emitter instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//replaces document.ready
EventEmitter.on('load', function() {
    $('.contactform').submit(function() {
         // ....
    });
});
</script>
```

I would suggest putting the EventEmitter in the head so that it's available to the inline scripts, but put the script loads the combination.js at the bottom or in a $(document).ready() to avoid any potential hiccups.

Comment: Hi Jesse ... Thanks for the effort in trying to help, I appreciate it.
Wow I have to be honest, to put this code together would be really a guessing game for me as this seems very advanced - I hate to sound useless. I understand that this event emitter should be coded to wait for my combination.js file to finish loading and then fire the second javascript code which is for my form? I've put a js fiddle of what I think I should do but I don't know what I'm doing - https://jsfiddle.net/og38whz9/

Comment: @user3364730 the important part is just to have the `var EventEmitter = {` before any of the `EventEmitter.on(` or else it will throw an error. :)

Comment: Hi Jesse ... thank you so much bro! I tried using you code but the same thing happens as mentioned in my post / question above. If you had to go to the website I am working on http://www.accommodation.co.za/test/kwalucia/index.php ... and just click submit on the form (you don't have to fill anything in) ... you'll see the error validation message appears on another page (whereas it's supposed to show on the same page in a slide-down notification type style)

Comment: @user3364730 my apologies, my emitter code was missing a line. I've updated it in my answer, please copy it into your codebase again and try again ( from looking at your site everything is in the right spots ).

Comment: + 1 ... You know what I cannot understand? How some people are so willing to help out cos helping out takes time + effort! Thanks so much buddy ... Your solution has worked :) I appreciate it big time!!!

Comment: Hi Jesse ... I don't know if you could help me with my new situation. I've been working on the website trying to improve it and decided to add a parallax header to this page (still using your code) : http://www.accommodation.co.za/test/kwalucia/index-parallax.php BUT now that I've added more javascript to my combination.js file (to get the parallax working of course), I'm not back to square one :/  !!! In the combination file: http://www.accommodation.co.za/test/js/combination.js ... I added (I've put comments in this file) - 1) imagesloaded.js 2) enquire.js 3) skrollr.js and 4) _main.js ...

Comment: Now it seems like out of those 4 extra javascript codes ... imagesloaded.js is the one causing the issue. Why would I need imagesloaded.js anyway? I'm not sure how all these 4 JS scripts tie in together but I'm assuming the imagesloaded.js also does some sort of waiting which I think is a little redundant when all I am using in the parallax is ONE image ... I'd appreciate your help

Comment: This is where I got the parallax script from: https://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/ (maybe good to use for your future projects)